# How do I read data from Firebase Database using the Firebase APIs

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently working on a basic app that will show you all of the Activity's Lifecycle callbacks using Firebase. What this requires me to do is read all of the data I have stored in the database. However, I cannot access it. Is there any way I can have access to my data through the API rather than having to look at the console directly?

Comment: There is an Android SDK that allow you to access the Firebase Database from your app. Read all about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), or get started with it by taking the [Android codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I got around it by updating a value that was not going to be shown to the user but was in the scope of the listener after attaching said listener.